# obtener los datos de una tabla de una base de datos SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Estoy realizando una pequeña aplicación en android con kotlin, soy bastante novato en esto... Ya he creado la base de datos, la tabla, hago el insert, pero me gustaría hacer en una activity un select de esa tabla y mostrar los datos... No lo consigo...

Este es mi código de obtener los usuarios

```
//función para obtener usuarios
fun getUsers(): ArrayList<User> {
        val usuarios = ArrayList<User>()
        val db = writableDatabase
        val selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM NOMBRE_TABLA"
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val nombre  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_NOMBRE))
                val apellidos  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_APELLIDOS))
                val usuario = User(nombre, apellidos)
                usuarios.add(usuario)
            }
        }
        cursor.close()
    return usuarios
    }
}
```

creo que me los devuelve correctamente, pero ahora no se como devolverlos a la vista... Este es mi método en mi activity

```
fun listado(){
    var db = Database(this, "pacDesarrollo", null, 1)
    db.getUsers()
}
```

He conseguido que no me de fallo, pero no se como debo mostrarlos...

Creo que he encontrado la solución para mostrarlos. Un listView

pero al intentar mostrar mis datos ahí, el LogCat deveulve el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

Y como estoy creando el adaptador, es:

```
fun listado() {
    var db = Database(this, "pacDesarrollo", null, 1)
    val users = db.getUsers()

    adaptador1 = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, users)
    vista.setAdapter(adaptador1)
}
```

Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si vas a usar el layout del "item" SDK debes realizarlo de esta forma

```
adaptador1  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                users
                            );
```

Si usas un layout personalizado que se llame `activity_list_item` , lo realizaras de esta forma:

```
adaptador1  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                                R.layout.activity_list_item,
                                users
                            );
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Jorgesys y perdona mi ignorancia.. Pero pretendo mostrar en un listView que se llama "listado2" los datos de mis usuarios, entonces el ArrayAdapter, será de tipo User¿?? si hago lo que me dices de ponerle tipo String, devuelve el error "None of the following functions can be called". No entiendo muy bien los argumentos que tendría que enviar al array adapter, ya que habría que pasarle un layout, no? pero mi layout no se llama así, en todo caso se llama activity_consultar_datos... Pero no me aparece en las sugerencias después del "."